# Farm account missing from SPSearchDBAdmin role on all 4 Search Service databases

Tags: 2013, search, crawl, searchserviceapplication

I have just set up SP2013 Search Services with a topology that spans 2 query servers and 2 index servers. The database servers live on a separate SQL server. Crawling is working but when I try to delegate the Search admininstration functions from Central Admin, I get this error: "Cannot alter the role "SPSearchDBAdmin", because it does not exist or you do not have permissions." I can see that the group exist and the farm account is a member, but don't know enough about the permissions it has. From my understanding, the farm account should be db_owner on all SharePoint databases. It appears to only have public access. Has anyone ran accross this. I would think that the permissions would automatically be given to the farm account. To be fair, I am using Todd Klindt's PowerShell script (the script is great and easy to follow!) to install search services and topology. Because I used PowerShell instead of the Central Admin wizard, could that be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue with a client. They did not have the logins entered into SQL for all the farm service accounts that would eventually be used. We used a separate account for the Search Service Application then the farm account, but all you'll need to do is:
1. Log in to the SQL Server Management Studio with an account with SysAdm role
2. Either add the service account you want to use for Search or choose the existing account that is running the service.
3. Under user mappings, select each searched database and add the account to the SPSearchDBAdmin role on the databases.

That should provide the account with the proper access for configuring search components.